# How to install zless in alpine linux?

Tags: logging, docker, alpine-linux

I am running a docker container from, alpine-linux image. It contains `zcat` but not `zless` and `zgrep`. How to install it in the container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming a fresh image, update the package index:

```
apk update
```

Then add the gzip package, containing `zless`, `zgrep` etc.:

```
apk add gzip
```

See the package contents here: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?branch=v3.5&name=gzip&arch=aarch64&repo=main

If you're wondering why `zcat` is included but not the other tools, even though `zcat` is in the `gzip` package, it's included as part of another package:

```
/ # apk info --who-owns $(which zcat)
/bin/zcat symlink target is owned by busybox-1.25.1-r0
```

Comment: Thank you grahamlyons. Can I install only `zless` selectively from `gzip` package?

Comment: No, I don't know of any package manager which supports that feature.